# Custom post type thumbnail / Media Library WP_DEBUG notice

Tags: post-thumbnails, media-library

My custom post type thumbnail appears to be working correctly.

However, when I return to edit one of my species profiles (in the Admin area, not talking about the front-end here), the following text scrawls directly above my featured image in its meta box:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /home/my/domain/public-facing.com/public_html/wp-includes/media.php on line 537

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /home/my/domain/public-facing.com/public_html/wp-includes/media.php on line 537

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /home/my/domain/public-facing.com/public_html/wp-includes/media.php on line 543

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /home/my/domain/public-facing.com/public_html/wp-includes/media.php on line 543

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /home/my/domain/public-facing.com/public_html/wp-includes/media.php on line 550

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in /home/my/domain/public-facing.com/public_html/wp-includes/media.php on line 550
```

I know I can have these messages ignored by changing `WP_DEBUG` but I'm not willing to do that at this stage (still developing the CMS).

[image: Error screenshot]

**EDIT**

The only code I'm using to achieve this feature is this line in my plugin:

`'supports' => array('author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')`

.. and this line in my theme's functions.php:

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'species' ) );`

** EDIT 2 **

The error is actually occurring on my Media Library page too:

[image: Media Library error]

** EDIT 3 **

Here is the code from `media.php`. Lines 537 to 550.

```
    if ( ( $data['width'] == $size[0] && $data['height'] <= $size[1] ) || ( $data['height'] == $size[1] && $data['width'] <= $size[0] ) ) {
        $file = $data['file'];
        list($width, $height) = image_constrain_size_for_editor( $data['width'], $data['height'], $size );
        return compact( 'file', 'width', 'height' );
    }
    // add to lookup table: area => size
    $areas[$data['width'] * $data['height']] = $_size;
}
if ( !$size || !empty($areas) ) {
    // find for the smallest image not smaller than the desired size
    ksort($areas);
    foreach ( $areas as $_size ) {
        $data = $imagedata['sizes'][$_size];
        if ( $data['width'] >= $size[0] || $data['height'] >= $size[1] ) {
```

** EDIT 4 **

This error also appears when I don't use a string format for `<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'indexleft-species-thumb' ); ?>`. If I use `<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(200,200) ); ?>` it will display the same errors as above.

** EDIT 5 **

var_dumps as requested:

`array(2) {[0]=> int(80) [1]=> int(60) } array(3) { ["file"]=> string(30) "Amazonas-English-1-288x381.jpg" ["width"]=> string(3) "288" ["height"]=> string(3) "381" } array(2) { [0]=> int(80) [1]=> int(60) } array(3) { ["file"]=> string(30) "Amazonas-English-1-339x450.jpg" ["width"]=> string(3) "339" ["height"]=> string(3) "450" } array(2) { [0]=> int(80) [1]=> int(60) } string(0) ""`

`array(2) { [0]=> int(80) [1]=> int(60) } array(3) { ["file"]=> string(45) "Acrochordonichthys-rugosus-2-Nonn-288x140.jpg" ["width"]=> string(3) "288" ["height"]=> string(3) "140" } array(2) { [0]=> int(80) [1]=> int(60) } array(3) { ["file"]=> string(45) "Acrochordonichthys-rugosus-2-Nonn-450x219.jpg" ["width"]=> string(3) "450" ["height"]=> string(3) "219" } array(2) { [0]=> int(80) [1]=> int(60) } string(0) ""`

Etc, etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you supply the code your using to add the thumbs?

Comment: Yep, we need the code . but generally speaking, This error would occur if any of the variables were actually strings or null instead of arrays.. check your variables for misspelled variables, or empty ones , or wrong array keys.

Comment: Do you have a post type registered called `species`? One suggestion would be to namespace your post type and call it something like `xyz_species` to ensure another plugin or theme doesn't already have that. It won't fix your problem probably but is good to do anyway! On another note, it would be good to see what hooks you are using, ie. your entire code for the post type and theme support. :)

Comment: Hi Jared, thanks for the input. Yes, the custom post type I'm referring to is `species`. Do you mean the entire code, or just the segment where I register the post type? If the former, the plugin is nearly 4,000 lines of code. There are no conflicts - all of the plugins being used in this (it's a heavily bespoke CMS) are written by myself. The code for theme support on the other hand is exclusively what I added to my post. It's a built-in WP feature so the code of the meta box isn't written by myself.

Comment: Updated my post again - I've now found the error in my Media Library too!

Comment: Can you install xdebug at all so we can get a stack trace of the bug?

Comment: Hi studioromeo. I've updated my post with some additional information. I've never used xdebug, and when I've looked at the installation instructions it looks a tad complex for my ability level!

Comment: What WP version are you using? Have you tried to deactivate all the plugins and tried it without them?

Comment: @dunc I meant just when you register the post type. It's not important or relevant really but merely a suggestion. :) Anyways, can you somehow do a check to make sure the variables are set before you start using them with `isset()` or even make sure they're arrays with `is_array()`? It would most likely get rid of the notices.

Comment: Like I wrote on my first comment - verify that all the variables are there , set , not null, and of the right type . you have some array which is a string, or null or empty or not set.

Comment: @JohnnyPea 3.3 and I've uninstalled all but my custom plugin as it's in that Custom Post Type which the problem is occurring. @krembo99 I really don't know which variables you're referring to. As I stated in my post, and in the comment following yours, the only two lines of code I'm using for these featured images is the "add_theme_support" line in `functions.php` and the "supports" line in `sf-species-profile.php`.

Comment: dunc, can you please add a `var_dump($size)` and `var_dump($data)` on line 536? and show us the result?

Comment: @HameedullahKhan done. Added to OP.

Comment: @dunc, can you also do the var_dump($post_id) on the same line? Its the $data var that is causing those warnings. If you will dump the $post_id you will know exactly on what attachment it causes those warnings.

Comment: @HameedullahKhan When I do that, and visit the Media Library, it simply prints the ID of each attachment. However, what you have made me realise is that it's only affecting certain images. I'm going to delete those images now and try re-uploading.

Comment: Is that the entirety of what your post type supports (they don't have titles?)? Can you share the rest of your register_post_type function call? What action are you hooking into where you enable your custom post type and the post thumbs (i.e. 'init', 'after_theme_setup')? Does this happen on posts too or just species?

Comment: can you create a paste bin of your plugin and show us you code? also any other plugins installed? and are you seeing this only on your new post type or on regular posts as well?

Comment: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19908

Comment: Any progress over here?

Comment: Hi kaiser. This mysteriously seemed to go away one day, amidst other changes to the site. I was never able to pin the problem down! Should I answer my own question with this information or would you like to simply close it?

Comment: @dunc: Please post your answer if you find the solution. I'm having the same problem and haven't found a solution. I guess it's because of WP (the way it handles array of sizes). But with the same code, in my localhost it's ok, but in my live site it's buggy. I'm confused.

Answer (score -1):

$data is not verified if it's array, then workaround patch is as following.

media.php:535

```
foreach ( $imagedata['sizes'] as $_size => $data)
    {
        if ( is_array($data) ) {
      // already cropped to width or height; so use this size
            if ( ( $data['width'] == $size[0] && $data['height'] <= $size[1] ) || ( $data['height'] == $size[1] && $data['width'] <= $size[0] ) ) {
                     $file = $data['file'];
                                list($width, $height) = image_constrain_size_for_editor( $data['width'], $data['height'], $size );
                                return compact( 'file', 'width', 'height' );
                        }
                        // add to lookup table: area => size
                        $areas[$data['width'] * $data['height']] = $_size;
        }
    }
```